# Can't find open ports python

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a simple portscanner in python - which tries to see if ports 0-10000 are open, and then appends them to an array. However, even if I open a port, it still does not recognise that the port is open.

Thanks

Code:

```
import socket
import threading

ip = "127.0.0.1"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM
open_ports = []
def porttry(ip, port):
    try:
        s.connect((ip, port))
        print("Port opened on %d" % port)
        open_ports.append(port)
        return True
    except:

        return None

for port in range(0, 10000):
    threading.Thread(target=porttry,args=(ip,port)).start()
    if port%100==0:
        print(port)
```

Comment: have you also looked into --> https://libnmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ This is the neat way to do so btw.

Comment: @NishantSingh I have, but I'd like to learn why this is going wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this code to work you need to create the socket separately for each connection (each thread).

The following works:

```
import socket
import threading

ip = "127.0.0.1"
open_ports = []
def porttry(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((ip, port))
        print("Port opened on %d" % port)
        open_ports.append(port)
        s.close()
        return True
    except:
        return False

for port in range(0, 10000):
    threading.Thread(target=porttry, args=(ip,port)).start()
    if port % 100 == 0:
        print(port)
```

It detects ports opened with, e.g., `nc -l 1777`.